# Количество слов в предложении

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Не могу разобраться с циклом. Мне надо узнать количество слов в предложении, а получается количество символов без пробелов.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
cout << "Введите предложение: ";
char str[100];
cin.getline(str, 100);
int j, words, i = 0;

while (str[i] != '\0'){
    i++;
}

int spc = 32;

words = 0;

int k = 128;
int b = 0;

for(j = 1;j < i; j++){
  for(k=128;256>k;k++){
        if (str[j] == char(k)){
            b++;
            if(str[b] != char(k)){
                words++;
            }
        }
    }
}

cout << words << endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
cout << "Введите предложение: ";
char str[100];
cin.getline(str, 100);
int j, words, i = 0;

while (str[i] != '\0'){
    i++;
}

int spc = 32;
if(i>0)
    words = 1;
else
    words = 0;

for(j = 1;j < i; j++){
  if(str[j-1] != ' ' && str[j] == ' '){
      words++;
  }
}

cout << words << endl;
}
```

Самый простой способ посчитать слова, это подсчет пробелов между словами)

Comment: Это думаю не очень подходит, так как можно ввести несколько пробелов, а не один.

Comment: Фёдор поправил, теперь будет считать и с несколькими пробелами)